# turtlebot calibration no IR scan using Hydro

Tags: calibration, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't get the turtlebot to calibrate using the turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch file.  It just outputs "Still waiting for scan" and I can see that the IR sensor never turns on.  The kinect works fine when I've tried gmapping though so I know it does work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114146/turtlebot-calibration-no-ir-scan-using-hydro/) by [jdd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3869/jdd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-12-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would guess it's the same issue discussed here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/112391/nothing-published-to-scan-under-hydro/

Nothing is published to /scan (which is required for calibration) unless `depth_registration` is set to false.  You might try:

`roslaunch turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch depth_registration:=false`

I can't test it directly because I'm using Kobuki-based turtlebots.

---

Originally posted by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) with karma: 228 on 2014-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0